# How to implement code for OAuth 2.0 Authorization for Google Directory API Without Command Line Interface

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, wordpress-rest-api

I have seen code in google directory api documentation for command line interface and have worked with it, the code works fine. But I want write code that runs without terminal and runs when on a page when the page is loaded because i have to run the code in the terminal every hour after it's expired, is there anyway i can get the code to run when i visit the page of authorization code.

The code work's with command-line interface, but i want it to work without command-line, what can i do?

Given Below is the code from Google Directory API and the URL:

URL : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/php

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('G Suite Directory API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

// Print the first 10 users in the domain.
$optParams = array(
  'customer' => 'my_customer',
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'email',
);
$results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);

if (count($results->getUsers()) == 0) {
  print "No users found.\n";
} else {
  print "Users:\n";
  foreach ($results->getUsers() as $user) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $user->getPrimaryEmail(),
        $user->getName()->getFullName());
  }
}
```

I have also tried to implement the code from OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications in wordpress page with the template but it's not working, which is from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#php_1

and this is my code:

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('G Suite Directory API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
    $client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
      $service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
    } else {
      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
```

Comment: Please define  "work without command-line" how do you expect this code to run?   Is this a web application or a background application.   It needs to be authorized in some way.   What's wrong with the webserver version?  "not working" is not a very good description of the issue.

Comment: @DaImTo sorry for the description, i am new here, i don't have that much experience in questioning, i have tried to edit it as much as i can, do help if you have any idea about directory api

Comment: Check the token.json file there should be a refresh token in there correct?  If so it should not be expiring.  The refresh token should be requesting a new access token as it needs

Comment: Lets start with what exactly are you trying to do here?  Is this designed to be a cron job? are you running this on a website?

Comment: @DaImTo thank you for your reply, I am trying to run this code on a wordpress website, i have token.json file which runs fine but i have to run `php quickstart.php` code in cpanel terminal every hour because the access token has to be refreshed again with refresh token, so i want it to work in a webpage, i should be able to run quickstart.php page without the need for terminal, that's what i'm saying.

Comment: @DaImTo i have also tried cron job in cpanel with `/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/quickstart.php`

Comment: What do you mean run on a web page do you want people to have to login to their own accounts?